# Task Scheduler run process after another process has run n-times

Tags: task, scheduled-tasks

i have two programs A and B, and i need to run A, A, B, where each process should start directly after the previous process has finished. Now i am aware of how to implement the A, A or A, B logic via the 'on event' trigger. However i am not aware if i can modify the same logic to have B run after A has run two or more times consecutivly.